# wxwidgets connect multiple functions

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am trying to connect a button to two different functions in different classes. The problem is, whenever I connect the second function, the connection to the first one seems to be gone

```
windowpointer->Connect( wxbuttonID, wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED,
(wxObjectEventFunction) (wxEventFunction) (wxCommandEventFunction) &class1::func1, NULL, (wxEvtHandler*) myclass1);

windowpointer->Connect( wxbuttonID, wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED,
(wxObjectEventFunction) (wxEventFunction) (wxCommandEventFunction) &class2::func2, NULL, (wxEvtHandler*) myclass2);
```

I'd appreciate any suggestion to fix this very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first event handler found gets the event first and if it doesn't call `event.Skip()` as part of its processing, no other handlers are called. So if you want to use more than one handler for an event you need to ensure that your event handlers do call `wxEvent::Skip()`. See [the event handling processing overview](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html#overview_events_processing) for more information.

Also notice that it's usually a bad idea, i.e. confusing to both the programmer and the user, to handle command events such as `wxEVT_BUTTON`, in multiple places. You'd expect a button click to be handled exactly once and while you can have multiple handlers for it, it is unlikely to be a good idea.

Comment: The situation where multiply event handler methods are used is plugin system. For example, both PluginA and PluginB have to handle the same event, so maybe PluginA::OnEvent1() and PluginB::OnEvent1() were connected(bind) to the same event. BTW, I think people will get confused by the word "event handler", sometimes, they refer to a method which will be called when some event happens. But sometimes, the event handler refer to the wxEvtHandler object, which just acts as a event source or event queue, and the wxEvtHandler object will call the event handler method once it got some event.

Answer (score -1):

The second Connect call will replace the first one.

Maybe have a method (say onXXXButtonClicked) that calls class1::func1 and class2::func2, and Connect the button to onXXXButtonClicked.

Comment: This is incorrect, it is possible to have several handlers for the same event, they are just called in order.